# Don't understand this unexpected indentation error

Tags: python, zip

I'm trying to create this looping script to extract a ton of files from a single folder. I've used a similar loop before where no error like this has occurred. The current code I'm using is:

```
import csv
import zipfile

with open("C:/Users/Peter Cui/Desktop/STACAN/ALLTABLES.csv", 'r') as CSV_LIST:
    READER = csv.reader(CSV_LIST)
    READ_LIST = list(READER)

COUNTER = 0
while COUNTER < 1:
    LIST_ROWNUM = READ_LIST[COUNTER]
    ENTRY_NUM = LIST_ROWNUM[0]
    print(ENTRY_NUM)
    with zipfile.ZipFile("C:/Users/Peter Cui/Desktop/STACAN/" + ENTRY_NUM + "-eng.zip", 'r') as ZIP_EXTRACT:
    ZIP_EXTRACT.extractall("C:/Users/Peter Cui/Desktop/STACAN/EXTRACTED")
    ZIP_EXTRACT.close()
    COUNTER = COUNTER + 1
```

With this code, I get the error:

```
    ZIP_EXTRACT.extractall("C:/Users/Peter Cui/Desktop/STACAN/EXTRACTED")
              ^
IndentationError: expected an indented block
```

Yet looking at it, it doesn't seem like adding an indent there would help me at all. Am I doing something utterly wrong?

Comment: You get the error because before that line you are using `with:`

Comment: @Carsten Not sure how I'd fix that. Haven't been using Python for long and I got the extraction code from the internet

Answer (score 0):

When you use `:` delimitator, you need to indent the next line.

Like this:

```
for abcd in mylist:
    print(abcd)
```